# Choosing a new laptop for programming: Lenovo g500 (intel GPU) or lenovo g580 (dedicated GPU)

Tags: graphics-card, lenovo-laptop

I need help to choose my new laptop.

I'm going to use it, mainly, for programming, internet, multimedia (see HD videos in internet) and basic tasks of images edition (Photoshop-like).

I like of Lenovo their keyboard and their prices.

So, I'm currently deciding between these two:

Lenovo G500 Intel Core i7 3612QM / 8 GB RAM / 1 TB HDD  (Not dedicated graphic card)

Lenovo G580 Intel Core i7 3520M / GT 710M / 6GB RAM / 500 GB HDD

Why is better for me? any opinions of the models (not only technical specifications, but also screen, sound, noise, etc.)
Have a graphic card dedicated worth (it's better) for me than the intel hd graphics 4000?

Probably, I'll use linux, so here one point up for the integrated I guess, since nvidia optimus is not offering too good support for linux right now.

Comment: 1) This is currently off topic, please refine it to make it a better fit for a Q&A site (No product recommendations) 2) Why bother optimizing the machine if you are going to run Photoshop in WINE? Any performance gains will mostly be lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Internet does not need much processing power (or graphics power) at all
2. Multimedia shouldn't be a problem. The Integrated Intel GPU is fine for standard tasks.
3. Depends how complicated the image editing will be, but again, the graphics card SHOULD powerful enough. If you are going to use Linux, I would recommend GIMP over photoshop as it's open source and native. I never did any large image editing projects, so I may be wrong.
4. Unless if you are going to test 3D games you make (or play any 3D game in the first place) on the same machine, CPU and RAM is A LOT more important than graphics. Having as many cores as possible is good too. You want the fastest compile times, don't you ;)

I do not own any of these laptops, just a notebook with Intel graphics ;)

This info should help you decide.

Comment: I'd add to check on sata ports and disk speed: i'ts the most important thing on a laptop! And remember, many laptops are SATA2, also if producers say "sata3 compatible".

Answer (score 0):

I currently own a laptop similar to the G500: it is a Lenovo i7 with 1tb hdd and 6gb ram, and no dedicated graphic card. I have to say that I really miss the dedicated card when using apps such as photoshop, indesign and illustrator.

Of course I have not compared the models to each other, but I definitely feel that next time I would go for the model with the dedicated video card.